# Reduction of structure group to Borel and flag of subbundles of the associated vector bundle

Tags: vector-bundles

Why is a reduction of the structure group of a principal $GL(n)$-bundle to a Borel subgroup the same as a flag of subbundles of the associated vector bundle of this principal bundle?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Borel subgroup $B(n)$ of $Gl(n)$ is isomorphic to the group of upper triangular matrices which preserves a family of vector supspaces $V_i\subset V_{i+1}$ and dimension of $V_i=i$, this implies that if $p:P\rightarrow M$ has a $B(n)$ reduction defined by $(U_j,g_{jk}$, $g_{jk}$ preserves $V_i$ and defines a flag of vector bundles $p_i:P_i\rightarrow M$ whose typical fibre is $V_i$.

Comment: Thank you very much! I am really sorry, but what does it mean that a $B(n)$-reduction of $P$ is defined by $(U_j,g_{jk}$, $g_{jk}$)? I thought that a B(n)-reduction of a $GL(n)$-bundle $P$ is an isomorphism of $P$ and the associated bundle $Q \times^{B(n)} GL(n)$ where $Q$ is a principal $B(n)$-bundle?